# Rails - Elastic Beanstalk AWS - sessions not maintained

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just deployed a Rails 3.2.17 app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I was first unable to login to the application (we use Devise) and kept getting `WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` in the logs.

Then when I tried to see the session in the Chrome developer tools, there was no cookies set for the application which is super weird.

Then I tried printing out the `session` has from the `ApplicationController` and every time I got different `session_id`.

```
{"session_id"=>"e0f2ccf03d07f48def5c4fbb872f2c0c", "last_action_time"=>Wed, 23 Sep 2015 08:40:09 EDT -04:00, "test"=>"test"}
....
 {"session_id"=>"0f9ef3aaf150619ac408da2bac4f51ae", "last_action_time"=>Wed, 23 Sep 2015 08:43:24 EDT -04:00, "test"=>"test"}
```

This is in my `session_store.rb`:

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: ENV['SESSION_NAME'], domain: :all
```

Do I need to do anything else? Thanks! This app works fine in a single EC2 instance (staging environment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `domain: :all` was the culprit. It assumes TLD lenght is 1 and mine was not. Removed it and things went back to normal. If you want to maintain session across subdomains (the purpose for `domain: :all`), you can specify the domain explicity.